# How to display two or more logcat filters at the same time in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, logcat, android-logcat

I have declared two LOG.i such as followings in my code:

```
Log.i("pen", pen.toString);
Log.i("book", book.toString);
```

Then I added these two filters to my Logcat window (via Edit Filter Configuration):

Filter1 with 'LOG TAG' set to pen
Filter2 with 'LOG TAG' set to book

I have no problem to see them each individually (by selecting them each in drop-down filter in logcat window).

NOW What I need to know is HOW to display both filters at the same time?

Comment: thanks for answers, Creating a new Filter with pipe symbol  ' | ' (to separate tags) will do the job however I am more interested to know without creating a new filter (which has both tags) is there anyway to just display result of two filters on fly Without creating a brand new filter? something like command line in search box , perhaps a something like Linux comand line :  adb logcat | grep -e book -e pen

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Have you tried using regex? Do as the screenshot below and you should see both tags at the same time

[image]

For copy/paste: `(pen|book)`

Note this accepts any number of tags as long as you separate them with `|`

Comment: This answer was very close to what I was looking for however if you really want to know how to do this without creating a new filter then see my response.

Answer (score 6):

> Thanks for all responses, they all were really helpful, however I found what I was looking for, if you really do not want to create a new filter just copy and paste something similar (pen|book) to the Search box on the main logcat window and do not forget to tick Regex box next to it.
>   [image]

Answer (score 1):

Via the `Edit filter configuration`, create or edit a filter with `Log Tag(regex)` (or check regex depending on the version of android studio) set to

```
pen|book
```

I can not take a screenshot now, I'm sorry.

Otherwise using the command line you can do (on linux)

```
adb logcat | grep -e book -e pen
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried separating both values by coma or semi-colon or |?

LOG TAG: pen, book

or

LOG TAG: pen; book

or

LOG TAg: pen|book

Comment: thanks for answer, Creating a new Filter with pipe symbol  ' | ' (to separate tags) will do the job however I am more interested to know without creating a new filter (which has both tags) is there anyway to just display result of two filters on fly Without creating a brand new filter?